# How to change version of Eigen

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, eigen, eigen3

In my [ROS package](https://wiki.ros.org/eigen) I would like to use a last stable version of [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) which is 3.3.4.

However when I check my version into package by `EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION, EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION, EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION` I have got a 3.3.90.

In my CMakeList:

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(include ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}
```

find_package for specific version does not exists.

So how can I change the version? I downloaded Eigen from official [github](https://github.com/eigenteam/eigen-git-mirror). I built it by`sudo make install` I got a log that everything is updated.

> Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/eigen3/...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was very very simply, when I clone from githube it was the newest version...

You can find the last stable version on [official Eigen web](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page). Then download, and follow the INSTALL instructions. So create build folder, cmake src_directory, sudo make install which will copy all headers into /usr/include/eigen3/.. then you can use version which you compile.

I suppose that as Eigen has only .h files you don't really need compile lib only do find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED PATH ...) but I didn't test this solution.